# how can i change this behaviour of select tag in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Here is my problem:

I've got a select tag with two options - "Hello" and "World"

html

```
<select>
<option> Hello </option>
<option> World </option>
</select>
```

In IE when you choose an option and and it becomes the selected option the blue highlighting remains until you click somewhere else outside the select tag. (In firefox it's not that way)

SO I wrote a script removes focus from the element when an option has been selected.

script

```
$('select').change(function() {
        $(this).blur();
```

But still one little problem stays: if i choose Hello and then gain Hello option - the focus will remain and the blue highlighting. But if I choose hello and then world option -everything works..
I read that For select menus, the change event occurs when an option is selected!!!But the option has to be different from the previous selected to trigger the change event.

**Is there any way this blue highlighting not to occur even if you choose again the same option.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a click event on select options, assuming select has id `select`:

```
$('option').click(function() {
    $('#select').blur();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DJCe7/

**EDIT**

If options are added dynamically, then do (assuming select has id `select`:)

```
$('#select').on('click', 'option', function() {
    $('#select').blur();
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Get same result pressing enter:

```
$('#select').keydown(function(event) {
    // Enter pressed
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        $('select').blur();
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DJCe7/10/

Comment: Simon thos reallu works with my first option - which is default ; but what about when the options are dynamically added!

Comment: How do you add them dynamically? Only options or whole select box?

Comment: I add only options dynamically!!like this {
  var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
  optn.text = modtext;
  optn.value = value;
  optn.title=text;

  selectbox.options.add(optn);
    }

Comment: TTGank you Simon :)  You are great. Thank you thousand times

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again! Unfortunatelyy now i see that there is one case in which the focus stays. Imagine that you click on the select and of couse you see all the options and you see that the highlighted option in blue  is what you want (so there is no need to click on it) - and you just press enter to select that option-so in this case there is no click event on the option and the highlightening stays

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25530/discussion-between-user1966221-and-simon)

Comment: thank you thank yu very much but as soon as i get happy i found a probleem. there  is one last case (i ray it's the last) case is almost the same as the previous - you click on the select and of course you see all the options and you see that the highlighted option in blue is what you want ) - but this time you decide not to press enter to select that option, but  just to click again on the select -so in this case there is no click event on the option, no pressing of enter and no change event and the highlightening stays

Comment: Sorry dude, I didn't find a way to solve that :-( You may consider using another solution, have a look at jQuery UIs Autocomplete/ComboBox: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score -1):

How about blurring it on focus? Not sure how this will behave in IE though.

```
$('select').focus(function() {
   $(this).blur();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b26f5/

*Edit:* Silly me, you could actually just remove the outline with CSS. No need to use Javascript!

```
select, select:focus, select:active { outline: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b26f5/1/

Comment: Why the downvote? Surely the CSS option must be the best way to go!?

Comment: The javascript prevents the select box from opening at all in IE9 and 10.

Comment: @MattCain Yea i figured IE wouldn't hadle it very well, hence my CSS solution. If the goal is to simply remove the focus styling the CSS solution will do just fine.